# Enabling Push Notifications for an app ID that doesn't use the team ID prefix

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications, provisioning-profile

So, my situation is as follows:

I work for a company where we are developing an iOS app. Let's call my company Acme and the app Explosives. The bundle ID for our app is `com.acme.explosives`.

We are currently developing support for push notifications, so my question is related to that. The explicit app ID we need to use to enable push notifications (since you can't enable push notifications for wildcard app IDs) has an app ID prefix of `YYYYYYYY`, so the full explicit app ID is `YYYYYYYY.com.acme.explosives`. Our team ID is `XXXXXXXX` (the explicit app ID was created before team app ID prefixes were introduced).

The SSL certificates we have created for Push Notifications on the server side were generated from the app ID of `YYYYYYYY.com.acme.explosives`.

Up until now we have been distributing the app with a provisioning profile which uses a wildcard app ID, but since we want to enable push notifications, that is no longer possible.

Now, it seems that we don't have any code signing certificates with the ID `YYYYYYYY` available in the iOS Member Center, and it's unclear to me how to create one.

So, my question is: What is the best way forward? Is it even possible to get this working? I have tried to contact Apple in order to try to migrate our app ID to the team app ID prefix, but they have so far been unhelpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two emails and a phone call Apple finally helped us migrate the app ID to our team ID prefix.